# How to restrict the charecter count that can be imputed into a Dokan product title field?

Tags: php, html, dokan

I need to restrict the character count that can be entered into the below.

```
<div class="dokan-form-group">
  <input type="hidden" name="dokan_product_id" id="dokan-edit-product-id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post_id ); ?>"/>

  <label for="post_title" class="form-label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product Name', 'dokan-lite' ); ?></label>
  <?php dokan_post_input_box ( $post_id,  'post_title', array( 'placeholder' => __( 'Product name..', 'dokan-lite' ), 'value' => $post_title ) ); ?>
  <div class="dokan-product-title-alert dokan-hide">
    <?php esc_html_e( 'Please enter product name!', 'dokan-lite' ); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screen shot of front end input:
[image]

Comment: [HTML <input> maxlength Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp), you'd probably need to create another entry (`'maxlength' => 'whateverTheMaxLimitShouldBe'`) into the same array as placeholder.

Comment: Hello, thank you I did try adding 'maxlength' but because the type is 'hidden' not 'text' it did not work...

Comment: You did `<?php dokan_post_input_box ( $post_id,  'post_title', array( 'placeholder' => __( 'Product name..', 'dokan-lite' ), 'maxlength' => '10', 'value' => $post_title ) ); ?>` and it didnt work, yes?

Comment: Also please provide the full generated HTML output.

Comment: Also provide how you want to restrict it. Maximum length only? Or minimum length only? Or both maximum and minimum length?